# Convert ext4 to btrfs with kernel > 4.0

Tags: kernel, btrfs, convert

I'm thinking about converting the data disk of my little home server from ext4 to btrfs.

After some reading I came over the btrfs-convert (from package btrfs-tools),
that allows in-place conversion from ext2/3/4 to btrfs.

But the btrfs Wiki says, that this feature is "not often used or well tested anymore" since the 4.0 kernels.

Has anyone experience with btrfs-convert and a 4.x kernel?
Is it a good Idea to try?

**Background Info**:

- The drive i'd like to convert is a 6TB HDD
- it's filled with 3.9TB data in a ext4 with the default block size
- Files are quite heterogenous: my photos and documents are thousands of small files, my VM disk images are a few gigabytes

**Note**: Yes, I have backups... two to be precise ;-)